# High and low speed modes in a humanoid

Tags: insectoid, winged-humans

Can we get a humanoid capable of both endurance and high speed if the use 2 different locomotion modes?

[image: lanky boy]
The idea i have is to have a lanky humanoid that is set up for slow speed long endurance walking/jogging, long plantigrade strides. If we also give it 4 small wings ([4 vs 2](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/12719/what-are-the-advantages-of-four-wings-over-two-wings/12751#12751)) does that mean its also capable of short hops. Flight would be More like a chicken flying (short-bursts/climbing aid) than a falcon (speed/agility) or pelican (Soaring/distance), maybe with some 'skipping' from the legs to help it airborne and staying within ground effect.

Not sure if near horizontal flight is a problem.
Would it need to have a different back and wing attachment. You cant really have any forward throw/stroke on the wings if the body is in the way. Maybe a tapering bodyrear section is needed, ie collectors. That way the wings can go around the body a bit.
[image]

Or would it better to have these overly complicated wing-base things?

[image]

My in head canon for this is what if a insect origin primate-analog evolved amongst island mangroves. Needs to move around branches but doesn't want to land because there is dangerous things in the water, so it retains some flight ability for tree hopping and climbing aid. But then transitioned to a desert/arid mainland.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Hi Tom Bebop, you're going into a lot of places at once; It makes it hard to understand what you actually need. Take one question at a time, starting with what is the most important to you :).

Comment: Thx, I've trimmed some of the fat from the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer: Yes.

Longer answer:

Think about Running vs Walking. They are two different modes of locomotion. And not by a little bit either. When at a full sprint, we are airborne, we are using the tips of our toes (Aka the 'Clean heels') we are using our upper body to counterbalance ourselves with exaggerated arm movements.

Now, compare to walking, we are primarily landing on our heels, we always have one foot on the ground, whilst we still use a bit of upper body to balance, it's not the same as running.

Evolutionary - there are many creatures that have a low-intensity/high-intensity form of locomotion, some even using different sets of limbs (think a primarily ground-dwelling bird like the Pukeko that still retains the ability to fly) - so there is plenty of scope for realism if you want it.

Comment: I guess that was what the question was more about, that walking was the slow speed. and that the high speed mode was flight as opposed to running and what if anything could be achieved by this. Thanks for your answer.